# Search on FireStore Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use the Firebase FireStore in Quote App on Android. But now I do not know how to find the data that I want.

Firestore provide the method .whereEqualTo ("your_field", "condition") but you have to type exactly where to find the data that you want.

This is an SQL statement:

```
WHERE CustomerName LIKE% or% Finds any values that have "or" in any position.
```

And I want to search all the data in a field in the Document on the same on FireStore. Is there any way? please help people, thank you very much.

Comment: Cloud Firestore only support so-called prefix matches, which are similar to SQLs `LIKE 'abc%'`. It does not support wildcard matches, such as SQLs `LIKE '%abs%'`.

Comment: thank you, really dispointed

Comment: If you want to allow full-text search, consider adding a full-text search solution. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/search

Comment: How to implement in Android Studio :D :D